# Cookies are stored with fetch but not with axios

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios

I'm fighting with a dumb issue which I don't understand. I have two apps: Front-End app written in React + TypeScript and using Axios to make API calls; Back-End app written in NestJS.

In NestJS I have installed cookieParser, I set cors, everything what I know what to set:
My **main.ts**:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie'],
  });
  await app.listen(5069);
}
```

My controller method where I'm sending cookies as a response to FE:

```
@Post('/')
@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
async login(@Body() body, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {
  const token: string = await this._authService.login(body.data);

  res
    .cookie('auth_token', token, {
      maxAge: 86400000 * 7,
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
    })
    .json({ statusCode: HttpStatus.OK });
}
```

And in my React app I'm using axios and I have case where I want to make a login API call, so I have function for it:

```
export const authUser = async (data: IAuthUser) => {
    try {
        const response: AxiosResponse<IResponseAuthUser> = await axios.post("http://localhost:5069/auth/", {
            withCredentials: true,
            data: data
        });

        return response;
    } catch (error: unknown) {
        const err = error as AxiosError;

        throw err;
    }
}
```

In the Network tab in devtools I have response header with cookie but the cookie is not setting in Application -> Cookies tab:
[image]
[image]

You can see the time difference between this post and cookie time, because I'm trying a different solution but the result is always the same. Also when I use fetch instead of axios, then everything is okay and cookie is stored in Application -> Cookies tab. But I want to use axios and I don't know what else I have to set to achive the same result as I have when I'm using fetch method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found solution.
I moved data which I want to send to the Back-End to second argument in `axios.post` method and now it work:

```
const response: AxiosResponse<IResponseAuthUser> = await axios.post("http://localhost:5069/auth/", 
        { data: data }, 
        { withCredentials: true });
```

I have no idea why axios has two places where you can set your data, maybe someone will explain. Anyway, maybe it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Hi ! In case you're still wondering why you need to give a second parameter, it's because axios will always consider the first argument as your data. So it doesn't matter that you're using **withCredentials** or **foo** within it, it will just send it as data.

By giving it as a second argument, you're basically telling to axios "Here's the configuration", hence why it's now working as intended.

You can find more informations here : https://github.com/axios/axios